# Adjusting Monthly Time Series Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this.

[image]

As you can see, the data corresponds to end of month data. The problem is that the end of month date is not the same for all the columns. ( The underlying reason is that the last trading day of the month does not always coincide with the end of the month. )

Currently, the end of 2016 January have two rows "2016-01-29" and "2016-01-31." It should be just one row. For example, the end of 2016 January should just be 451.1473  1951.218  1401.093 for Index A, Index B and Index C.

Another point is that even though each row almost always corresponds to the end of monthly data, the data might not be nice enough and can conceivably  include the middle of the month data for a random columns. In that case, I don't want to make any adjustment so that any prior data collection error would be caught.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this goal.

EDIT:

```
            Index A  Index B Index C
DATE                                
2015-03-31  2067.89  1535.07   229.1
2015-04-30  2085.51     1543   229.4
2015-05-29  2107.39      NaN     NaN
2015-05-31      NaN  1550.39   229.1
2015-06-30  2063.11  1534.96     229
2015-07-31  2103.84      NaN   228.8
2015-08-31  1972.18  1464.32     NaN
2015-09-30  1920.03  1416.84   227.5
2015-10-30  2079.36      NaN     NaN
2015-10-31      NaN  1448.39   227.7
2015-11-30  2080.41   1421.6   227.6
2015-12-31  2043.94  1408.33   227.5
2016-01-29  1940.24      NaN     NaN
2016-01-31      NaN  1354.66   227.5
2016-02-29  1932.23  1355.42   227.3
```

So, in this case, I need to combine rows at the end of  2015-05, 2015-10, 2016-01. However, rows at 2015-07 and 2015-08 simply does not have data. So, in this case, I would like to leave 2015-07 and 2015-08 as NaN while I like to merge the end of month rows at  2015-05, 2015-10, 2016-01. Hopefully, this provides more insight to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.resample(rule='M', how='last')
```

to create a new `DateTimeIndex` ending on the last day of the months and sample the last available data point for each months. `fillna()` ensures that, for columns with of missing data for the last available date, you use the prior available value.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful suggestion. But, the problem with this approach is that it will completely remove the unusual data from the middle of the month. 

More importantly, there might be cases where the end of month data might not be available. In that case, I want to leave it as NaN rather than filled it with value from previous month.  

So, basically, I only want to use 'fillna' and 'ffill' method only in the last days of the months. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please include any cases you want considered in your data sample (and please provide the later so that it can be copied, not as an image). You are probably going to need to use `groupby` with `TimeGrouper('M')` to operate on individual months data, either in a loop or using `apply()` depending on how many conditions you want to use.

Comment: the first thing that came to my mind is to loop over each month and decide. But, I was hoping there would be a better way. fillna and resample are definitely a good start. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to to selectively apply fillna method. I edited the question. hopefully, it is clearer now.

Comment: see edit, untested but should get you started. the tricky part will be to decide which values to leave unchanged and which to collapse using `.fillna()`, might require some logic of sorts.